# FSK Demodulation Code (Android)

Tags: android

I am intending to perform FSK demodulation and came across the Androino Project(https://code.google.com/p/androino/source/browse/wiki/AndroinoTerminal.wiki), which reads in data from the Adruino into the phone's audio jack, which is pretty darn cool.

I am trying to go through the code but I can't make sense of some impt values. :((

Why is the  bit-high = 22 peaks, bit-low = 6 peaks, private static int HIGH_BIT_N_PEAKS = 12 and private static int LOW_BIT_N_PEAKS = 7?? And why is it 136 samples per encoded bit?

Am I also right to say that the FSK rate of the Adruino is set at 315Hz?

I have attached the hardware(softTerm) codes as well: https://code.google.com/p/androino/source/browse/trunk/arduino/SoftTerm/SoftModem/SoftModem.h and the cpp file is in there as well. Dun have enough reputation points to post both links.

```
    /** Copyright (C) 2011 Androino authors                       
    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");               
    * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.              
    * You may obtain a copy of the License at               
    *               
    *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0               
    *               
    * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software           
    * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,             
    * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.              
    * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and           
    * limitations under the License.                
    */
     package org.androino.ttt;

     import android.util.Log;

     public class FSKModule {
    // Experimental results
    // Arduino sends "a" character (97) 1100001 
    // The generated message is 0110.0001
    // 136 samples per encoded bit
    // total message = 166 bits: 155(high)+1(low)+8bit+stop(high)+end(high)

    private static int SAMPLING_FREQUENCY = 44100; //Hz
    private static double SAMPLING_TIME = 1.0/SAMPLING_FREQUENCY; //ms

    // reading zero+155(high)+1(low)+8bit+stop+end+zero
    private static int FREQUENCY_HIGH = 3150;
    private static int FREQUENCY_LOW = 1575;

    //high: 7 samples/peak
    //low : 14 samples/peak
    // 1492 samples/message low+8bits+stop+end 
    // 136 samples/bit  (=1492/11)
    private static int SAMPLES_PER_BIT = 136;

    private static int ENCODING_SAMPLES_PER_BIT = SAMPLES_PER_BIT/2; // 68

    // bit-high = 22 peaks
    // bit-low = 6 peaks
    private static int HIGH_BIT_N_PEAKS = 12;
    private static int LOW_BIT_N_PEAKS = 7;

    private static int SLOTS_PER_BIT = 4; // 4 parts: determines the size of the part analyzed to count peaks
    private static int N_POINTS = SAMPLES_PER_BIT/SLOTS_PER_BIT;  // 34=136/4

    private static double PEAK_AMPLITUDE_TRESHOLD = 60; // significant sample (not noise)
    private static int NUMBER_SAMPLES_PEAK = 4;                     // minimum number of significant samples to be considered a peak

    private static int MINUMUM_NPEAKS = 100; // if lower it means that there is no signal/message

    private static final int BIT_HIGH_SYMBOL=2;
    private static final int BIT_LOW_SYMBOL=1;
    private static final int BIT_NONE_SYMBOL=0;

    private static final int CARRIER_MIN_HIGH_BITS=12;

    private static final int SOUND_AMPLITUDE = 31000;

    private static final String TAG = "FSKModule";

    private FSKModule(){
    }

    private static void debugInfo(String message){
            //System.out.println(">>" + message);
            Log.w(TAG, "FSKDEC:"+ message);
    }




       //-----------------------------------------
       // DECODING FUNCTIONS
       //-----------------------------------------     

    public static boolean signalAvailable(double[] sound){
            FSKModule m = new FSKModule();

            int nPoints = N_POINTS;
            int nParts = sound.length / nPoints;
            int nPeaks = 0;  
            int startIndex = 0;
            int i = 0;
            do {
                    int endIndex = startIndex + nPoints;
                    int n = m.countPeaks(sound, startIndex, endIndex);
                    nPeaks += n;
                    i++;
                    startIndex = endIndex;
                    if (nPeaks > MINUMUM_NPEAKS) return true;
            } while (i<nParts);
            if (nPeaks >3)
                    debugInfo("signalAvailable() nPeaks=" + nPeaks);
            return false;
    }

    public static int decodeSound(double[] sound){
            FSKModule m = new FSKModule();
            // processing sound in parts and
            //Log.w(TAG, "ENTRO EN processSound");
            int[] nPeaks = m.processSound(sound);
            if (nPeaks.length == 0) // exit: no signal detected 
                    return -1;

            //debugInfo("decodeSound nPeaks=" + nPeaks.length);
            // transform number of peaks into bits 
            //Log.w(TAG, "ENTRO EN parseBits");
            int[] bits = m.parseBits(nPeaks);//-------------------------> OK!!
            //debugInfo("decodeSound nBits=" + bits.length);
            // extract message from the bit array
            int message = m.decodeUniqueMessage(bits, sound, nPeaks);
            debugInfo("decodeSound(): message="+message + ":" + Integer.toBinaryString(message));
            return message;
    }

    private int decodeUniqueMessageCorrected(int[] nPeaks, int startBit){
            int message = 0;

            // process nPeaks starting from the end  
            int index = (startBit+12)*SLOTS_PER_BIT;

            // find zero -> non zero transition
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                    int i2 = nPeaks[index-i];
                    int i1 = nPeaks[index-i-1];
                    debugInfo("zero->nonzero index=" + (index-i) + ": i2=" + i2 + ":i1=" + i1);
                    if ( (i1-i2)>2) {
                            index = index-i-1;
                            break;
                    }
            }
            debugInfo("zero->nonzero index=" + index);
            int[] bits = new int[2+8+1+2];
            for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
                    int peakCounter = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                            peakCounter += nPeaks[index-j]; 
                    }
                    debugInfo("decode corrected: peakCounter="+i + ":" + peakCounter);
                    if (peakCounter > 7)  { //LOW_BIT_N_PEAKS)
                            bits[i] = BIT_LOW_SYMBOL;
                    }
                    if (peakCounter > 12)  { //LOW_BIT_N_PEAKS)
                            bits[i] = BIT_HIGH_SYMBOL;
                            message += Math.pow(2, i);
                    }
                    debugInfo("bit=" + bits[i] + ":" + message);
                    index = index -4;
            }
            debugInfo("decode corrected: message="+message + ":" + Integer.toBinaryString(message));
            message = 0;
            for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
                    if ( bits[i] == BIT_HIGH_SYMBOL) {
                            message+= Math.pow(2, 7-(i-2));
                    }
            }
            return message;
    }

    private int decodeUniqueMessage(int[] bits, double[] sound, int[] nPeaks){
            // start bit
            int index = findStartBit(bits, 0);
            debugInfo("decodeUniqueMessage():start bit=" + index);
            if (index == -1) return -1; // no start-bit detected
            if (index + 8 + 2 > bits.length)
                    throw new AndroinoException("Message cutted, start bit at " + index, AndroinoException.TYPE_FSK_DECODING_ERROR);


            // debugging information
            int number = 16; // n bits to debug
            for (int i = index-5; i < index-5+number; i++) {
                    debugInfo("decodeUniqueMessage(): bits=" + i +":" + bits[i] );
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < number*SLOTS_PER_BIT; i++) {
                    int position = i + (index-5)*SLOTS_PER_BIT ;
                    debugInfo("decodeUniqueMessage(): npeaks=" + position+ ":" + nPeaks[position] );
            }

            // 8bits message
            int value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    int bit = bits[index+i];
                    if (bit==BIT_HIGH_SYMBOL) value+=Math.pow(2, i);
            }
            // stop bit: do nothing
            // end bit: do nothing
            debugInfo("MESSAGE          =" + Integer.toBinaryString(value) + ":" + value);

    */
            int correctedMessage = decodeUniqueMessageCorrected(nPeaks,index);
            debugInfo("MESSAGE corrected=" + Integer.toBinaryString(correctedMessage) + ":" + correctedMessage);
            return correctedMessage;

    }

    private int findStartBit(int[] bits, int startIndex){
            // find carrier and start bit
            int index = startIndex;
            int highCounter = 0;            
            boolean startBitDetected = false;
            do {
                    int bit = bits[index];
                    switch (bit) {
                    case BIT_HIGH_SYMBOL:
                            highCounter++; // carrier high bit

                            break;
                    case BIT_LOW_SYMBOL:
                            if (highCounter>CARRIER_MIN_HIGH_BITS) { // start-bit detected
                                    startBitDetected = true;
                            }
                            else highCounter = 0; // reset carrier counter
                            break;
                    case BIT_NONE_SYMBOL:
                            highCounter = 0;// reset carrier counter
                            break;
                    }
                    index++;
                    if (index>=bits.length) return -1; 
            } while (!startBitDetected);
            return index;
    }

    private int[] parseBits(int[] peaks){
            // from the number of peaks array decode into an array of bits (2=bit-1, 1=bit-0, 0=no bit)
            // 
            int i =0;
            int lowCounter = 0;
            int highCounter = 0;
            int nBits = peaks.length /SLOTS_PER_BIT;
            int[] bits = new int[nBits];
            //i = findNextZero(peaks,i); // do not search for silence
            i = findNextNonZero(peaks,i);
            int nonZeroIndex = i;
            if (i+ SLOTS_PER_BIT >= peaks.length) //non-zero not found
                    return bits;
            do {
                    //int nPeaks = peaks[i]+peaks[i+1]+peaks[i+2]+peaks[i+3];
                    int nPeaks = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < SLOTS_PER_BIT; j++) {
                            nPeaks+= peaks[i+j];
                    }
                    int position = i/SLOTS_PER_BIT;
                    bits[position] = BIT_NONE_SYMBOL;

                    debugInfo("npeaks:i=" + i + ":pos=" + position+ ": nPeaks=" + nPeaks);
                    if (nPeaks>= LOW_BIT_N_PEAKS) {
                            //Log.w(TAG, "parseBits NPEAK=" + nPeaks);
                            bits[position] = BIT_LOW_SYMBOL;
                            lowCounter++;
                    }
                    if (nPeaks>=HIGH_BIT_N_PEAKS ) {
                            bits[position] = BIT_HIGH_SYMBOL;
                            highCounter++;
                    }

                    //if (nPeaks>5) bits[position] = 1;
                    //if (nPeaks>12) bits[position] = 2;
                    i=i+SLOTS_PER_BIT;


            } while (SLOTS_PER_BIT+i<peaks.length);
            lowCounter = lowCounter - highCounter;
            debugInfo("parseBits nonZeroIndex=" + nonZeroIndex);
            debugInfo("parseBits lows=" + lowCounter);
            debugInfo("parseBits highs=" + highCounter);
            return bits;
    }

    private int findNextNonZero(int[] peaks, int startIndex){
            // returns the position of the next value != 0 starting form startIndex
            int index = startIndex;
            int value = 1;
            do {
                    value = peaks[index];
                    index++;
            } while (value==0 && index<peaks.length-1);
            return index-1;
    }

    private int[] processSound(double[] sound){
            // split the sound array into slots of N_POINTS and calculate the number of peaks

            int nPoints = N_POINTS;
            int nParts = sound.length / nPoints;
            int[] nPeaks = new int[nParts]; 
            int startIndex = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int peakCounter = 0;
            do {
                    int endIndex = startIndex + nPoints;
                    int n = this.countPeaks(sound, startIndex, endIndex);
                    nPeaks[i] = n;
                    peakCounter += n;
                    i++;
                    startIndex = endIndex;
            } while (i<nParts);
            //} while (startIndex+nPoints<sound.length);
            debugInfo("processSound() peaksCounter=" + peakCounter);
            if (peakCounter < MINUMUM_NPEAKS) {
                    nPeaks = new int[0];
            }
            return nPeaks;
    }

    private int countPeaks(double[] sound, int startIndex, int endIndex){
            // count the number of peaks in the selected interval
            // peak identification criteria: sign changed and several significant samples (>PEAK_AMPLITUDE_TRESHOLD) 

            int index = startIndex;
            int signChangeCounter = 0;
            int numberSamplesGreaterThresdhold = 0;
            int sign = 0; // initialized at the first significant value
            do {
                    double value = sound[index];
                    if (Math.abs(value)>PEAK_AMPLITUDE_TRESHOLD) 
                            numberSamplesGreaterThresdhold++; //significant value
                    // sign initialization: take the sign of the first significant value
                    if (sign==0 & numberSamplesGreaterThresdhold>0) sign = (int) (value / Math.abs(value));
                    boolean signChanged = false;
                    if (sign <0 & value >0) signChanged = true;
                    if (sign >0 & value <0) signChanged = true;

                    if (signChanged & numberSamplesGreaterThresdhold>NUMBER_SAMPLES_PEAK){
                            signChangeCounter++; // count peak
                            sign=-1*sign; //change sign
                    }
                    index++;
                    //debugInfo(">>>>>>>index=" + index + " sign=" + sign + " signChangeCounter=" + signChangeCounter + " value=" + value + " numberSamplesGreaterThresdhold=" + numberSamplesGreaterThresdhold);
            } while (index<endIndex);
            return signChangeCounter;
    }
```

}

Comment: Did you ever figure out these numbers?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I think the numbers above do not correspond to a a standard such as 1200 or 300 Bd modems.